# TFS file changes being included across team projects, and ignored files still shown as added

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

My TFS workspace has multiple team projects in it. Such as:

```
TeamProjectA
TeamProjectB
TeamProjectC
```

We are using TFS 2012. Lets say I have work going on all three of these at the same time. I want to check my changes in for `TeamProjectA` so I go to Team Explorer in Visual Studio (2012 or 2013) > Pending Changes, and the Included Changes section often has all modified files from each team project included, even though the team explorer is currently set to `TeamProjectA`. I always have to right click the parent solution folder of the solution for the team project I want to check in and then "Exclude Unselected". So thats my first problem. I know I am going to accidently include changes from other projects with my check-in at some point.

I also have some `.dat` files that are generated/overwritten during the build process and compiled into my `dll`. I want to exclude these files from source control, so I select them in Solution Explorer > File Menu > Source Control > Advanced > Exclude [file]. The glyph in Solution Explorer changes to a red circle with a black dash indicating it is excluded. When I go to Source Control Explorer, those files still show as an `add` though with the green `+` glyph. I even added an `ignore.tfignore` file with `\*.dat` but they still show up. How can I get these files to be ignored?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you exclude a pending change, you still *have* that pending change, so it will still appear as "added".  The difference between included and excluded is what will be checked in when you click the "Check In" button, but it will remain a pending change until you either undo it or check it in.

If you want these files to never be added in the first place, please make sure that your `.tfignore` lists them correctly.  Please make sure that:

1. You are using local workspaces.
2. The file is called `.tfignore` and not `ignore.tfignore`.

Comment: I've tried changing the file to `.tfignore` but it errors and says it must have a file name.

Comment: Well, `ignore.tfignore` will simply do nothing.  What is producing this error?

Comment: Windows is producing the error. try renaming a plain text file to .tfignore and it wont let you.

Comment: @Ethan if you can't change the file name in Windows Explorer, try `rename`ing the file from the command line.

Comment: got it renamed, still was continually including the .dat files in the "Included Changes" so I did a check in to see if maybe they would be dropped because of the `.tfignore` but they still went into source control. I then rolled back and it stopped showing them as pending. Tried a check in again, and it successfully did not include the .dat files. Thanks. Any idea what is happening with it trying to include files from other solutions?

Comment: This is by-design, sometimes a changeset needs to span multiple projects.

Comment: okay thanks. At least I know I'm not just doing it wrong now. I understand the possibility of changes spanning projects - especially in a single solution, but it seems dangerous to let changes span *Team* Projects.